# Can I develop and debug Metro applications in Windows server 2012 beta with the Visual Studio 11 developer preview?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Can I develop and debug Metro applications in Windows server 2012 beta with the Visual Studio 11 developer preview?

a license error occurs when I create a new metro project.
(I have no problem with Net connection)
[image: trying to create new metro app project on windows server 2012]

if I click 'Close', I can create a new metro project.
building project OK.
but I can't run the project. the license error occurs again.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need a license to deploy a Metro Style App. It does not seem like the current server build gives you the license, so no - you can't do it. If you want to create a Metro-looking app - you can do that with WPF or Silverlight and retemplate yourself or with something like [Elysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/).